# Error in import statement for PDFbox

Tags: java, apache, netbeans-8

I'm trying to use PDFbox. This is what i've done till now:

- Downloaded pdfbox-1.8.15-src.zip from https://pdfbox.apache.org/download.cgi
- Created library `pdfbox` in NetBeans 8.2, adding the extracted zip folder in the `Add JAR/Folder` option.
- Added the library to my project `project101`

but when I write the import statement as `org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDDocument` , it shows the error `package org.apache.pdmodel does not exist`.

Comment: You downloaded the sources. either build the project to create the jars, or download the jars (pdfbox and fontbox, or pdfbox-app).

Comment: Did my comment help or not?

Comment: Oh yeah thanks. I tried adding jars directly instead of creating the library, and it worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As discussed in the comments, you downloaded the sources instead of the jar files. The sources are to build your own version or to help with debugging or to look into if you're interested.

Additional hint: read the [dependencies page](https://pdfbox.apache.org/1.8/dependencies.html), you may need more jar files depending on what you do.

Second additional hint: if you're just starting, better use the 2.0 version, which has many improvements compared to the 1.8 version. (If you do that, do also read the [getting started](https://pdfbox.apache.org/2.0/getting-started.html) and the [dependencies](https://pdfbox.apache.org/2.0/dependencies.html) pages for that version).